# Calculation using symbols instead of assigned values

Tags: symbolic

How can I calculate with the symbols itself not using assigned values?

```
a = 2;
Simplify[a + 2 a]
```

This example returns `6` but I want `3a`.

```
a = b;
Simplify[a + 2 a]
```

And this example returns `3b` instead of `3a`.
I do not want to delete the value by `Clear[a]`.

**Motivation**

I have a complicated expression with many variables $x_i$. The same expression can be written much simpler by fewer variables $y_i$ that were defined by $x_i$. The $x_i$ however do not appear in my new equation. I now want to simplify the expression using only $y_i$. Because $y_i$ are defined by $x_i$ MMA is trying to use $x_i$ for simplification. However it is much simpler for MMA if it would use only $y_i$.

**Edit**

After reading the answers I am surprised that MMA has no simple functionality. Actually I thought that this would be a standard problem. I had expected there is a command like `IgnoreValue[]`.

Comment: This sounds like a "Doctor, it hurts when I do this" kind of issue. What is your workflow that you define variables as numbers, and *then* try to simplify expressions?  What are you trying to achieve with this?  Most likely there is a better solution to your real problem

Comment: @JasonB. I added an explanation why I want to do this.

Comment: Given your update, something like BobHanlon’s solution is probably a better way to go.

Comment: @lericr This would be only suitable if I want to hand over concrete values. But if I calculate symbolically I would have to hand over other symbols not reducing the complexity.

Comment: The question was closed due to "spelling mistakes". Could somebody explain why it was closed?

Comment: I don't think the closing reason is very suitable here… That being said, I think the issue people have with your question is that it seems to be a "non-sensical" request from the perspective of someone used to the way Mathematica works: It doesn't really make sense to tell MMA "a=b", and then expect an output like "f[a]", since MMA knows that a=b. If you want to use the knowledge "a=b" only in some places, don't make it a global definition. If you want to locally forget it, you can use `Block` (the rule will still used before returning the result, but not during the simplification at least)

Comment: One thing I just thought of: You could try to simply replace your `yi` with `Hold[yi]` - this will prevent them from being replaced by the `xi`, and most symbolic simplification functions can handle such compound symbols without issues.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 2;
backupa = a; Clear[a]
Simplify[a + 2 a]
a = backupa; Clear[backupa]

(* 3 a *)
```

or

```
a = 2;
With[{a = Defer[a]}, Simplify[a + 2 a]]

(* 3 a *)
```

Comment: Of course this is always possible but not very elegant if you have to backup many variables. I thought there is an inbuilt functionality.

Comment: The second variant does not backup anything.

Comment: Imagine you have to do this for 30 variables. This is not very comfortable.

Comment: Already better. Is it possible to use a single Defer if you have several variables? Maybe using a place holder, joker?

Answer (score 2):

I think some context explaining the motivation for doing this would elicit better answers, but here's an attempt at a way you might approach this.

```
SetAttributes[BlockSymbols, HoldAll];
BlockSymbols[symbols_List, exp_] := 
  Unevaluated[exp] /. 
    Thread[HoldPattern /@ Unevaluated[symbols] -> HoldForm /@ Unevaluated[symbols]]
```

You would apply it like this,

```
a = 5; b = 7;
BlockSymbols[{a, b}, a + 2 a - b^2]
(* 3*HoldForm[a] - HoldForm[b]^2 *)
(* but will look like 3*a - b^2 *)
```

The result has HoldForm wrapped around a and b, but it will visually match what you are asking for. You could use Defer in place of HoldForm, or maybe some other construct depending on what you're trying to do.

**Edit**

This might be simpler:

```
SetAttributes[BlockSymbols, HoldAll];
BlockSymbols[symbols_List, exp_] := Block[symbols, HoldForm[exp]]
```

The HoldForm will be wrapped around the entire expression in this case.

**Edit 2**

Oops, that second one doesn't simplify the arithmetic, but you can try this,

```
BlockSymbols[symbols_List, exp_] := Block[symbols, HoldForm[Evaluate[exp]]]
```

Comment: Edit 2 works, however fails in indirect cases:
```a = b;c = a;
BlockSymbols[{a}, Simplify[c + c]]``` does not return anything and ```a =1;c = a;
BlockSymbols[{a}, Simplify[c + c]]``` returns 2 instead of ```2a```.

Comment: You would block the symbol c, not a. The  point was to not evaluate c, so why would you expect 2a?

Comment: Blocking c does not yield the result 2a. If only a is blocked and c is equal to a then I would expect the result 2a.

Comment: @granularbastard `a=1;c=a` does not set `c` to `a`. It sets `c` to the value of `a`, which is `1`. To set `c` to `a`, use `c:=a` (or `Block[{a}, c = a]`, I suppose). `SetDelayed` is meant to be used for the assignment of unevaluated expressions, and `Set` is for evaluated right-hand sides.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Instead of assigning values to variables, only assign values with replacement rules;

```
param = {a -> 2, b -> 7};

expr = a + 2 a + 6 a*b // Simplify

(* 3 a (1 + 2 b) *)

expr /. param

(* 90 *)
```

Comment: I assume in my case that the variables have already values. So this suggestion might work for other cases.

Comment: @granularbastard If you need to frequently "jump back and forth", I believe using `Rule` (`->`) is the standard way. This is how _Mathematica_ is designed. (Just look at the output of `Solve`, `DSolve`, `RSolve`… )